# What kind of lens combinator is this?

Tags: ruby, haskell, lenses

I’m making a lens combinator in Ruby and I can’t figure out what the generally accepted name of it is. The unknown function composes two lenses that have the same source type and their target type (using  [Benjamin C. Pierce’s terminology](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~harmony/manual.pdf)) is a hash map. The unknown function takes in those two lenses and returns a new lens which has the same source type and target type as the original lenses.

It looks like this (Ruby syntax):

```
lens_a.get(source)
> {:title => "some title"}
lens_b.get(source)
> {:description => "some description"}
new_lens = unknown_function(lens_a, lens_b)
new_lens.get(source)
> {:title => "some title", :description => "some description"}
```

A diagram of the combinator I’m trying to build can be seen on slide 18 of [this presentation](https://bmaddy-public.s3.amazonaws.com/presentations/clojure.mn/lenses.pdf) (the slide’s title is “Merge?”).

I’ve looked at Haskell's [lens docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-1.2/docs/doc-index-All.html) (small parts of which I can understand), but I can’t figure out which combinator this is.

What is the standard name for the unknown_function above? If this lens doesn’t have a standard name, are there a few standard functions that can be composed to make it? If not, I’ll probably just call it merge.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using the lens 1.2 library instead of 4.1.2?

Comment: I'm doing this in Ruby. I don't know Haskell. I'm just looking there as a reference. I'll look at the 4.1.2 docs--thanks for the tip.

Comment: I couldn't find anything that specific in the lens library (odd, I thought), but I think something like `zipLenses` or `merge` would work.  In Haskell it could look something like `merge :: Lens' s a -> Lens' s b -> Getter s (a, b)`; `merge l1 l2 = to (\x -> (view l1 x, view l2 x))`.  Obviously this wouldn't work as a `Setter`, so it can't be a full `Lens`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have a link to your ruby lens code? I'd be interested in using it!

Comment: Yeah, it's embedded into [another project](https://github.com/projecthydra-labs/fedora_lens) right now. The code you're probably interested in is [here](https://github.com/bmaddy/fedora_lens/blob/lens_tests/lib/fedora_lens/lenses.rb). If you find any of that useful let me know and I might pull it out into a gem. Also, let me know if you have any questions on it, I'm happy to help clarify stuff.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that roughly the right idea for your combinator, in Haskell, is

```
merge :: Lens' s t -> Lens' s t -> Lens' s (t, t)
```

possibly generalized to

```
merge :: Lens' s t -> Lens' s t' -> Lens' s (t, t')
```

so that your two targets may differ in type. We could "implement" this as follows, but doing so will reveal a problem

```
merge l1 l2 = lens pull push where
  pull s          = (view l1 s, view l2 s)
  push s (t1, t2) = set l2 t2 (set l1 t1 s)
```

In particular, on the `Setter` side of this equation we explicitly *order* the way we put back our values. This means that we can use `merge` to easily build lenses which violate the lens laws. In particular, they violate the PUT-GET law. Here's a counterexample

```
newtype Only a = Only a

-- A lens focused on the only slot in Only
only :: Lens' (Only a) a
only inj (Only a) = Only <$> inj a

-- We merge this lens with *itself*
testLens :: Lens' (Only a) (a, a)
testLens = merge only only

-- and now it violates the lens laws
> view testLens (Only 1 & testLens .~ (1,2))
(2,2)
```

Or, in plain english, if we `merge` a lens with itself then the `Setter` side turns into two sequential sets on the same location. This means that if we try to set it with a pair of values which are different only the *second* set will persist and thus we violate the PUT-GET law.

The `lens` library tends to eschew invalid lenses so this combinator isn't available. The closest we have is [`alongside`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.1.2/docs/Control-Lens-Lens.html#v%3aalongside) which has the following (restricted) type

```
alongside :: Lens'  s     a
          -> Lens'  s'    a'
          -> Lens' (s,s') (a,a')
```

but, as you can see, this ensures that our *source* is also a product type so that the `Setter`s apply uniquely to each side of the source. If we were to try to write a `dup` `Lens` which we could compose with `alongside` to build `merge` we'll run into the same problem as before

```
dup  :: Lens' a (a, a) -- there are two possible implementations, neither are lenses
dup1 inj a = fst <$> inj a
dup2 inj a = snd <$> inj a
```

---

Now, all of this might be fairly technical and meaningless from a Ruby perspective. In Ruby you're not going to have compiler enforced type safety and so you'll likely blend a lot of the rules together and achieve less strictness. In such a case, it might be meaningful to implement `merge` with its sequential writes semantics.

In fact, based on the examples you've given, it looks like the counterexample I pointed out cannot even happen in Ruby since your target type is a Hash and ensures unique keys already.

But it's important to note that `merge` can be used to build improper lenses if you look at it hard enough. Fundamentally what that means is that in more complex scenarios, using `merge` can easily lead to weird bugs caused by it violating our intuitive sense for what a lens is. This may not be a huge problem for Ruby as complex abstraction is frowned upon in the Ruby community anyway, but that's why we have the laws.

Comment: This was a wonderful answer--thanks for taking the time to explain it so clearly. I especially appreciated the "in plain english" part since Haskell is still rather foreign to me (however, my interest is growing).

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be like you want to combine two lenses into a [traversal](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.1.2/docs/Control-Lens-Traversal.html#g:1).  I don't see that combinator anywhere, but I'm new to lens so I'm not sure what it would be called anyway.

Something like:

```
compoundEye :: Traversable tl => tl (Lens s t a b) -> Traversal s t a b
```

But, [the hoogle results](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%2Blens+Traversable+tl+%3D%3E+tl+%28Lens+s+t+a+b%29+-%3E+Traversal+s+t+a+b) are not promising.